# Getting the position of 2D ImageButton ArrayList

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I have a global 2D ArrayList named `ArrayList<ArrayList<ImageButton>> boardImageButtons`.

Inside the method `onClick(View view)`, I have the clicked Image Button named  `((ImageButton) view) btn`.

I would like to get the position ( `i` & `j` ) of that object in the 2D ArrayList.

I try to avoid running throw all the 2D ArrayList, comparing the objects and getting the `i` & `j` of the equals objects.

Do you have any better suggestions?

Is there any way to pass additional variables through `onClick(View view)`?

Comment: You can create a `Map` that marks your buttons to positions. 

Something like `Map<ImageButton, MyCustomXYPair>`

Answer (score 1):

Create a `HashMap` at the starting of your app.

```
class Pair {
    int x, y;
    Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}


Map<ImageButton, Pair> map = new HashMap<?>();
```

Initialize the map by putting all the values using some loop or your logic like

```
map.put(btn1, new Pair(1, 2));
..
..
```

And when retrieving the position, use

```
Pair myPair = map.get(view);
```